# How can i access anim folder's xml file?

Tags: android, animation

Working on animations, here I have created `anim` folder and created a file `myanimation.xml` inside this folder.
Now, I m getting an error

> "error: cannot find symbol variable myanimation" at the time of app
>   run.

Here my code

```
Animation aniSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanimation);
```

Comment: Your code is correct. May be issue is folder structure.

Comment: Did you follow this steps please check [here](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/create-anim-folder-animation-file)

Comment: Yes, I have followed these steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you created `anim` folder in wrong directory, move it to `res`

also in `myanimation.xml` file dont forget to add all nessasary tags.

for example it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="150"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toXScale="1.05"
        android:toYScale="1.05"/>

    <scale
        android:duration="150"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.05"
        android:fromYScale="1.05"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"/>
</set>
```

if you still get same error then do:

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` on Android Studio

Comment: anim folder is in res directory and i have uses all the necessary tags in xml file. I have also tried Invalidate Caches/ Restart, Still getting this error.

Comment: thats weird, maybe you need to loadLayoutAnimation? Also try to use different context

Comment: are you using different resources for different buildTypes ir flavors? it also might be a problem

Comment: No, I m not using different resources.

Comment: I just want to do an animation, which fills the color on whole screen starts from the center point of the screen.

Comment: How can I achieve this? can you suggest me something as I m a beginner?

Comment: why not just use scale animation? something like this? ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f) and then just add it to view and start it

Comment: no problem, please mark it as answered if it going to solve your problem.

Comment: @AntimArora Close Android Studio and Delete the cache in /System/Caches

Comment: @AntonisRadz Thanks for your help. Scale animation solved my problem

Comment: @AntimArora glad to hear, please mark it as answered or at least upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
`TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.animText);
 ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 3.0f, 0f, 1.5f, 
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.5f);
 animation.setDuration( 1000 );
 animation.setFillAfter( true );
 txt.startAnimation(animation);`

animation.xml,apply this to view
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#FFCF3C"/>
</shape>
```

This code worked for me.